# Is there a 'let' equivalent for setting an option only local to a buffer/window?

Tags: options, variables

When working with options that often have complex or calculated string values (e.g. `formatprg`, which might have additional parameters, separated by whitespace), it's often easier to use `let` to set them, i.e. `let &option='complex stuff'` rather than `set option=complex\ stuff`.

However, for options which are buffer or window-local, is there is a `let` equivalent which *only* sets the local value? `setlocal` does always, if the option supports a local value. However, the `&` prefix for options used with `let` does not appear to. [The docs for `let`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Alet-%26) say:

```
For an option local to a window or buffer the effect
is just like using the |:set| command: both the local
value and the global value are changed.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

For a local buffer/window option, you can use:

```
let &l:option = 'complex value'
```

And you can also be explicit about a global option, with:

```
let &g:option = 'complex value'
```

See [`:help :let-option`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Alet-option), which includes:

> ```
> :let &l:{option-name} = {expr1}
> ```
>
> Like above, but only set the local value of an option (if there is one).  Works like `:setlocal`.
>
> ```
> :let &g:{option-name} = {expr1}
> ```
>
> Like above, but only set the global value of an option (if there is one).  Works like `:setglobal`.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but I very quickly answered my own question, hadn't read far enough down in the docs! `let &l:option='value'` will set the local value, with `let &g:option='value'` explicitly setting the global value.

Comment: For variables: `b:` for buffer, `w:` for window scope